# Go illegal base64 data at input byte 0 when unmarshalling a string json

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I'm storing my data in a redis database and when I ask for it, I get a valid json back. The json looks like this:

```
{"Data":"hi","Hash":"000f7dcfca98450a0f405384db3878c1956cb98309e63cf2d0a963cff9f17260","PrevHash":"000daf177434acd55a3284787b793a3453c3d70eacdb9a84f5faed43adb2ff58","Nonce":8504,"TimeStamp":1611498968}
```

It's a valid json string (Go omits leading and traling quotes) but I get this error when unmarshalling. `illegal base64 data at input byte 0`

`err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(item), &block)`

```
type Block struct {
    Data      []byte
    Hash      []byte
    PrevHash  []byte
    Nonce     int
    TimeStamp int64
}

func (chain *BlockChain) AddBlock(data string) {
    var lastHash []byte

    item, err := chain.Database.Get(ctx, "lastHash").Result()
    Handle(err)
    lastHash = []byte(item)
    newBlock := createBlock(data, lastHash)

    _, err = chain.Database.Set(ctx, StrHash(newBlock.Hash), newBlock, 0).Result()
    Handle(err)
    _, err = chain.Database.Set(ctx, "lastHash", newBlock.Hash, 0).Result()
}

func (chain *BlockChain) Iterator() *BlockChainIterator {
    return &BlockChainIterator{
        CurrentHash: chain.LastHash,
        Database:    chain.Database,
    }
}

func (iterator *BlockChainIterator) Next() *Block {
    var block *Block

    item, err := iterator.Database.Get(ctx, StrHash(iterator.CurrentHash)).Result()
    
    Handle(err)
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(item), &block)

    Handle(err)
    iterator.CurrentHash = block.PrevHash

    return block

}

// -----------------
// Utility Functions
// -----------------

// TODO: Think about this. Wouldn't it be better to store everything as strings rather than converting it?
type jsonBlock struct {
    Data      string
    Hash      string
    PrevHash  string
    Nonce     int
    TimeStamp int64
}

// This function gets called automatically by go-redis
func (b *Block) MarshalBinary() ([]byte, error) {
    jb := jsonBlock{
        Data:      string(b.Data),
        Hash:      StrHash(b.Hash),
        PrevHash:  StrHash(b.PrevHash),
        Nonce:     b.Nonce,
        TimeStamp: b.TimeStamp,
    }
    return json.Marshal(jb)
}
```

Comment: Please post the minimal reproducible code snippet that causes error (including the `struct type` into which you are trying unmarshal).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Hash` value (and also `PrevHash`) in JSON is not the Base64 encoded form of the data, but rather a hexadecimal representation. If you try to unmarshal it into a Go value of type `[]byte`, the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package assumes and try to interpret it as Base64 encoded data.

Same goes for the `Data` field: it should be of Go type `string` since it is not the Base64 encoded form, so change it to `string`.

Try to unmarshal `Hash` and `PrevHash` into fields of type `string`, and do hexa decoding using [`hex.DecodeString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#DecodeString).

You may implement a custom unmarshaler to do this automatically.

A convenient way would be to create a `HexData` type that is a `[]byte` but decodes from hex string:

```
type HexData []byte

func (h *HexData) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var s string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &s); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    decoded, err := hex.DecodeString(s)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *h = HexData(decoded)
    return nil
}
```

Using it:

```
type Block struct {
    Data      string
    Hash      HexData
    PrevHash  HexData
    Nonce     int
    TimeStamp int64
}

func main() {
    var b Block
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &b); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", b)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/g4LuahJgGyM)):

```
{Data:hi Hash:[0 15 125 207 202 152 69 10 15 64 83 132 219 56 120 193 149 108 185 131 9 230 60 242 208 169 99 207 249 241 114 96] PrevHash:[0 13 175 23 116 52 172 213 90 50 132 120 123 121 58 52 83 195 215 14 172 219 154 132 245 250 237 67 173 178 255 88] Nonce:8504 TimeStamp:1611498968}
```

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the part of my code where I convert my `Block` into `jsonBlock`, so now it gets saved as base64 strings and it works correctly.